# Get color name by an objects's fill/ convert brush to string c#([uwp)

Tags: c#, colors, windows-10-universal, brush

I have a rectangle filled with a color(it's a different color each time). I want to be able to get the name of the color-for example "Green", through the color of the filling on that rectangle. Does anyone know how can I do that?
I have tried the following :

```
        Brush a = rect.Fill;
        Color color = ((SolidColorBrush)a).Color;
        string thecolor = color.ToString();
        switch (thecolor)
        {
            case "Red": furText.SelectedIndex = 0; break;
            case "Blue": furText.SelectedIndex = 1; break;
            case "Yellow": furText.SelectedIndex = 2; break;
            case "Pink": furText.SelectedIndex = 3; break;
            case "Green" : furText.SelectedIndex = 4;break;
        }
```

I am basically trying to change my combobox's selected default item to be that of the color of the filling of the rectangle.
by debugging I could see my code can infact get the brush, and even convert it to solid colorbrushs, however the solid color brush is in hex format, and I need the name itself.
Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this it works fine. your color name will be in selectedcolorname

```
        Brush a = rect.Fill;
        Color color = ((SolidColorBrush)a).Color;
        string selectedcolorname;
        foreach (var colorvalue in typeof(Colors).GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            if ((Color)colorvalue.GetValue(null) == color)
            {
                selectedcolorname = colorvalue.Name;
            }
        }
```